# How to use Powershell Where-Object like an IN statement

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I have the following code which works:

```
foreach ($db in $svr.Databases | 
         where-object {
         $_.name -eq "testDB" 
         -or $_.name -eq "master"
         -or $_.name -eq "model"
         -or $_.name -eq "msdb" } )
{
  write-output $db.name
}
```

Is a cleaner way to do this?

Something like:

```
foreach ($db in $svr.Databases | 
         where-object {$_.name -in "testDB, master, model, msdb" } )    
{
  write-output $db.name
}
```

Comment: 8kb, gentle nudge, but I think it would be worth accepting Andreas Covidiot's answer as it uses the actual `-in` operator in powershell

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the `-contains` operator. Like:

```
$dbs = "testDB", "master", "model", "msdb"

foreach ($db in ($svr.Databases | where-object {$dbs -contains $_.name  } )) {
    write-output $db.name
}
```

Use `help about_Comparison_Operators` to learn more about this and other comparison operators.

**Update:**

PowerShell v3 has added the `-in` operator. The example in the original question will work in v3.

Comment: Aren't you missing a paren there?

Comment: Yes, I did miss a paren. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: The example in the original question won't quite work - as it is a comma delimited string - not an array.

Answer (score 12):

You can use a regex:

```
$svr.Databases | where { $_.name -match 'testDB|master|model|msdb' } | foreach { $db.name }
```

Answer (score 7):

Powershell has an [`-in` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#-in-and--notin) since Powershell 3

```
$srv.Databases | where Name -in "master","model","msdb" | write-output { $_.Name }
```

**Further Reading**: [Docs on Comparison Operators > Containment Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#containment-operators)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add the most concise solution:

```sh
([array] $svr.Databases.Name) -match '^(testDB|master|model|msdb)$'
```

<sup>For an explanation of the RHS [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/47U8pT/1).</sup>

The above relies on:

- [Member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) to return the `.Name` property values of all elements of the `$svr.Databases` collection.

  - The `[array]` cast ensures that the result is *always* an array, even if only *one* property value happens to be returned.
- The ability of comparison operators such as `-match`, the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch), to act on *arrays* as the LHS, in which case they act as *filters* and return the *sub-array of matching elements*.

  - By contrast, the [`-contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains) operator and its PSv3+ counterpart, [`-in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in-and--notin) - the only difference between the two being the *order of operands* - only support a *literal* and therefore *single* comparison value, and only ever return a *single*, Boolean (`[bool]`) value that indicates whether the comparison value is *contained* (equal to an element of) the array operand.
  - Note: In the case at hand, the *literal* comparison values happen not to contain regex *metacharacters*, so they can be used as-is; if this assumption cannot be made, [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape) must be applied to the comparison values:

    ```sh
    $vals = 'testDB', 'master', 'model', 'msdb'
    ([array] $svr.Databases.Name) -match `
      ('^(' + ($vals.ForEach({ [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|') + ')$')
    ```